# Arduino Program Reset Bug

Tags: arduino-uno, watchdog

I'm using an Arduino Uno and ATMega328P to simply control a few LEDs with switches controlled by the user.  However, after about 56 iterations through my main loop (or ~16 seconds) my program resets.  I suspect it has something to do with the Watchdog timer, but even with it disabled via wtd_disable(); in my setup, the problem persists.  The program does enter a loop that it can only exit if the user flips a switch.  Any suggestions?

```
//Don't worry, I have all necessary libraries and variables set up.

void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial for output
  Serial.println(i2c_init());

  wdt_disable();

  //pinMode(22,INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(23,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(wakePin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ACPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(PowerPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(PowerLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ACLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Battery1LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Battery2LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(WifiLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TesterLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EnableLED, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, wakeUpNow, LOW);


}        

void loop()
{

  digitalWrite(PowerLED, LOW);
 // digitalWrite(ACLED, LOW);    Exclude AC Power LED
  digitalWrite(Battery1LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Battery2LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(WifiLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(TesterLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EnableLED, LOW);

  Enable = 0;

  Serial.println("Reset Complete");


  int ACPower = digitalRead(ACPin);
  digitalWrite(ACLED, ACPower);

  int v1 = fetchWord(deviceAddress1, VOLTAGE);
  int v2 = fetchWord(deviceAddress2, VOLTAGE);
  int BatteryVoltage = max(v1,v2);
  Serial.print("Highest Battery Voltage: ");
  Serial.println(BatteryVoltage);

  delay(250);

  if((BatteryVoltage >= 7000) | (ACPower == 1)){
    int PowerOK = digitalRead(PowerPin);
    if (PowerOK == 0){
      loop();
    }else {
      bulk();

    }
  }else{
    loop();
  }

}

//This is the main part of my code that is constantly looped through,
//and after 16 seconds, the program resets, going back to loop()

void bulk()
{

  Enable = 1;
  digitalWrite(EnableLED, HIGH);

  int ACPower = digitalRead(ACPin);
  digitalWrite(ACLED, ACPower);

  //int Battery1State = BatteryState(deviceAddress1);
  int Battery1State = 2;  // Simulating low battery
  switch (Battery1State){
    case 1:
      digitalWrite(Battery1LED, HIGH);
      break;
    case 2:   //I can't run parallel code to control the blinking LED, 
//so I toggle the LED every pass through.  Case 2 blinks slowly
    if(i >= 4){
      toggleLED(Battery1LED);
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
      break;
    case 3:  //case 3 blinks quickly
    toggleLED(Battery1LED);
        break;

  }
  int Battery2State = 3;  // simulating a very low battery
  switch (Battery2State){
    case 1:
      digitalWrite(Battery2LED, HIGH);
      break;
    case 2:
    if(j >= 4){
      toggleLED(Battery2LED);
      j = 0;
    } else {
      j++;
    }
      break;
    case 3:
    toggleLED(Battery2LED);
        break;

  }




  buttonState = digitalRead(wakePin);  //button is HIGH by default
  if(buttonState == HIGH){


    Serial.println(count);
    if(count == 0){
      starttime = millis();
    } else if (count == 54){
      endtime = millis();
      runtime = endtime - starttime;
      Serial.print("System Run Time: ");
      Serial.println(runtime);
    }

    count++;
    int PowerOK = digitalRead(PowerPin);

    digitalWrite(PowerLED, PowerOK);
    delay(250);
//Repeat this code if power switch is on, restart if power is turned off

    if(PowerOK == 0){

      loop();    
    }else {

      bulk();
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the code for the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect - how appropriate for a bug posted in this site - a stack overflow. I haven't really tried to understand your entire code, but from what I see, both functions (loop and bulk) call either loop() or bulk() at their end. In essence, the end of those functions is never reached.

For starters, try removing every call to loop() inside your code:

Change the code at the end of the loop function 
from:

```
  if((BatteryVoltage >= 7000) | (ACPower == 1)){
    int PowerOK = digitalRead(PowerPin);
    if (PowerOK == 0){
      loop();
    }else {
      bulk();

    }
  }else{
    loop();
  }
```

to:

```
  if((BatteryVoltage >= 7000) | (ACPower == 1)){
    int PowerOK = digitalRead(PowerPin);
    for ( ; PowerOK != 0 ; )
      bulk();
  }
```

and remove completely the following code at the end of your bulk() function:

```
delay(250);
//Repeat this code if power switch is on, restart if power is turned off

    if(PowerOK == 0){

      loop();    
    }else {

      bulk();
    }
```

Background:

When you call a function in C, C++ and most other languages, the return address (i.e. the place in your code where execution should continue after the called function ends) is placed on a special part of memory called the stack. When the called function returns, the return address is removed from the stack and all is well. If another function is called before the first one returns, a new return address is added to the stack. If a function repeatedly calls itself without ever returning, eventually the entire stack space (a limited resource) is used up and something bad happens. This is what happens in your code: the functions loop() and bulk() never return, instead they do their thing and call either themselves or the other one ad infinitum.

In arduino, there is an implicit main() function more or less like the following:

```
void main(void)
{
   // system initialisation code
   ...
   ...
   ...
   // user code
   setup() ;
   for( ; ; )
      loop() ;
}
```

That is, loop() is called continuously. There is no reason to call it again at its own end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still pretty new with programming so this explanation really helped.

Comment: If you think this is the correct reply to your query, you should consider marking it as the correct one (click on the check mark at the left of this answer). However, your previous reply would indicate that what I wrote is irrelevant. In this case, you should mark your own reply as the correct one. The whole point of this system is to indicate to other readers of the question which reply was more useful for you.

Comment: No problem, I'm trying to implement your solution to see if it works, as my program still seems to restart at moments.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I believe it was a Serial port overflow.  The problem resolved itself when I deleted some "Serial.println"s at the end of my code that I thought were irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

For arduino, when starting the setup() gets called once, then loop is called repeatedly (whenever it completes..
As mentioned there is no need for loop to ever call itself..